# How to use :contains(text) with any text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

With jQuery, one can use:

```
$(":contains(hello)")
```

It will return any matching element that contains the text "hello".

I want to be able to match any text, especially "hello :)".

```
$(":contains(hello :))") // Doesn't work
$(":contains('hello :)')") // Doesn't work
$(":contains('hello :\)')") // Doesn't work
```

How do I find elements that contains "hello :)" with jQuery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155213/how-do-you-escape-parentheses-in-jquery-selector) for how.

It basically involves `.filter` to get around [a known `:contains` bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5482):

```
$('#demo').filter(function(i, el) {
    return !!$(el).text().match(/hello :\)/);
});
```

Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sm68v/).

Note that performing `.length` on the result of this may give you a value *greater than* 1 even if only one element contains that text, because the element's parents will also match.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an open bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5482

And there is this [statement](http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg89408.html) of jakkob:

> I also found that the error comes only
>   if the bracket is at the very end of
>   the contains-expression.

Comment: This answer does not provide a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

from jQuery:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\

so try this

```
$(":contains('hello \\:\\)')")
```

Comment: weirdly enough `$(":contains(hello \:)")` will work for `hello :`. Just need to match the para

Answer (score 0):

Quick code:

```
jQuery.fn.contains = function(re) {
  return this.filter(function(i, el) {
    return !$(el).text().match(RegExp(re));
  });
};
```

This way you can do:

```
$("*").contains(":\\)") // returns all elements in the page that contains ':)'
```

Note: contains() accept a regular expression (meaning you need to escape whatever needs to be escaped for a regexp)