# jQuery selector problem when using a single parenthesis

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, escaping, contains, parentheses

If I include a single parenthesis in a :contains selector I get an error.

e.g.

```
$("a:contains('Speed (mph')")
```

returns the error

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   (mph')

if I add the closing parenthesis at the end, the statement runs fine. however, I need to be able to query where there is often a single parenthesis.

What's going on here and how do I sidestep this?

EDIT

In my actual code the :contains part is passed in as a variable

e.g

```
var searchText = 'Speed (mph';
var result = $("a:contains('" + searchText  + "')");
```

Comment: See [How do you escape parentheses in jquery selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155213/how-do-you-escape-parentheses-in-jquery-selector).

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Flaschen but that solution seems to deal only with finding element text that contains just a single left parenthesis. I need to pass in the `:contains` part as a variable that could be `speed(mp/h` or `speed(mp/h)`. I was unable to use the .match function to do this (I'm a bit of a jQuery noob) - Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `$("a:contains('Speed \\(mph')")`

From http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> If you wish to use any of the
>   meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a
>   literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two
>   backslashes: \. For example, if you
>   have an element with id="foo.bar", you
>   can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").
>   The W3C CSS specification contains the
>   complete set of rules regarding valid
>   CSS selectors.

Comment: Why does it have to be escaped in a quoted value?

Answer (score 0):

As from Matthew Flaschen's link, you could use the filter function like this:

```
    var searchRegex = new RegExp("Speed \\(mph","g");
    var result = $('a').filter(function(i, el) {
        return $(el).text().match(searchRegex);
    });
```