# jQuery contains with parentheses

Tags: jquery

I have divs containing round brackets that I want to look for using the contains selector.  But it's not returning the result.

```
<div class="amount">($123)</div>

$('.amount:contains("\\(")').length = 0?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a similar question with an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155213/how-do-you-escape-parentheses-in-jquery-selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `filter` instead of `:contains`.

```
$('.amount').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('(') !== -1;
})
```

Or you could use a regex instead of `.indexOf`:

```
$('.amount').filter(function(){
    return (/\(/).test($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: ":contains" is not a real CSS selector, so jQuery inside itself is using filter anyways.