# jQuery contains selector and special char

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a bit of trouble using jQuery contains selector;

Consider the following html and jquery to check if an element contains certain text.

For example
HTML:

```
<div>welcome :)</div>
```

jQuery Javascript:

```
$('div:contains("welcome :)")').length
```

If I run the above JS code for that HTML. It does not return 1 as it should.

However the following works as expected

```
$('div:contains("welcome")').length
```

Any suggestion how to accommodate for special characters like brackets or colon etc?

Comment: non-repro http://jsfiddle.net/FNrQX/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery selector value escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It breaks with jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: @Dennis Time for an upgrade. `:)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you escape parentheses in jquery selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1155213/1331430)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yeah, its time for an update

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be because of escape characters used in JQuery selector. You can use '\' character before the escape characters like ':' to resolve the problem. Also for general approach below function can be used.

```
function jqescape(str) { return str.replace(/[#;&,\.\+\*~':"!\^\$\[\]\(\)=>|\/\\]/g, '\\$&'); }
```

I tried for below expression it gave me result as expected:

```
$('div:contains("welcome \:")').length
```

Comment: It's not what OP is asking for; the problem is the `)` inside the `contains` filter which you omitted from your answer.

Comment: I think it is a bug in the contains method of JQuery. I tried it but it is pairing ')' with last open parentheses and that is why it is not identifying the same.