# jquery contains selector not working with inverted comma and breackt

Tags: jquery

I have following text in a table td (8" & 12")

My code is

```
var match = $('#table_body > tr > td:contains("' + searchterm + '")');
```

when I try to find (8" & 12") this getting following error

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :contains("")"

the last ") two characters are creating problem what it the solution I tried escape string (adding slashes) error is gone but no search result with this

Comment: can you post the HTML ?

Comment: <td>
      <div class="displayfields">10050 - Concrete - Place CMU Blocks above concrete footing (8" &amp; 12")</div>

  </td>

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use single quotes surrounding your `td:contains('some text with "quotes"')`. The documentation does not list using double quotes as a valid alternative. Note that you don't really need the surrounding quotes, you can just use bare words. It will work whether your text contains single or double quotes.

```
var match = $("#table_body > tr > td:contains('" +searchterm+ "')");
// or without quotes altogether
var match = $("#table_body > tr > td:contains(" +searchterm+ ")");
```

**Example:**

```js
var text = '8" 12"';
var text2 = '5" 6"'
var text3 = '2\' 4"';
var text4 = "Testing (1' 3')";


// Quotes are allowed 
$("div:contains('"+text+"')").css('background-color', 'red');

// But not necessary
$("div:contains("+text2+")").css('background-color', 'yellow');

// Works with mixed single and double quotes
$("div:contains("+text3+")").css('background-color', 'gray');

// However, it doesn't support parentheses, you'll have to search it yourself
// And make sure you escape regex special characters

// Escapes any special characters
RegExp.escape = function(s, flags) {
    return new RegExp(s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), flags);
};

console.log(RegExp.escape("1' 3')"))
$('div').filter(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).text().match(RegExp.escape("1' 3')"));
}).css('background-color', '#fef0e4');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>8" 12"</div>
<div>5" 6"</div>
<div>2' 4"</div>
<div>1' 3')</div>
```

Comment: i tried this but not working
var searchterm = '")';

$('#table_body > tr > td:contains("' + searchterm.replace(/"/g, "\\\"") + '")');

Comment: @NavneetGarg  The initial attempt didn't work, but I added an answer with a working example

Comment: yes this is working thanks but I am wondering if user type ') this than this code generate error

Comment: `:contains()` doesn't seem to support parentheses, I offered an alternative. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155213/how-do-you-escape-parentheses-in-jquery-selector